# Can i use Regextract with IF so if the text i want not found the formula searches for another term?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I use Regextract with Trim to cute phrases and variables out of the paragraph, the thing is that not all the time the paragraph has the same text but the values and variables are easy to get.

Now I want to have `regextract` works with IF so if found XX in the paragraph then enters the value next to it using TRIM, if not use another parameter to search and insert its value.

Please check the example, it should be more clear:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pUUTnbun3lhdOj1ejPQgbRMpXU8C6_HZ3ZWWDXc_3do/edit#gid=0

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Oh Hi @player0, how are you. i have made it public, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try perhaps like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(pending tasks) \d+ monday"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(not done tasks) \d+"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "Verify Pending (\d+)")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you it worked on the example on the sheet, i guess i misexplained the my issue. i updated the sheet now, would you kindly please check it.

Comment: Oh, im so sorry I didn't see that, thank you so much my lifesaver <3

Comment: Hi, @player0 I am facing another challenge now, I noticed that in my bot there is a "(s)" character before the numbers that I want to extract, which is not letting the formula to work. is there is a workaround for this?

I updated the sheet for this issue

Comment: use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "[Verify delay |Verify delay\(s\)] (\d+)")))`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you and bless your life <3